# Insufficient privileges to complete the operation while importing data from Microsoft Graph API using Python

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, msal

I am trying to import the data using Microsoft graph APIs in Python. I am not a Python developer so I am unable to do so. I don't really have an idea how to use Secret_Key_Name and Secret_ID but I am guessing they act as username and password. I particulary need help with this. When I just use rest of the 3 keys, I am getting this error.

```
API Request Error: 403-{"error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.","innerError":{"date":"2023-08-14T13:31:49","request-id":"[Request ID]","client-request-id":"[Client Request ID]"}}}
```

Python Code:

```
import requests
import msal

client_id = "[Client ID API Key]"
client_secret = "[Client Secret API key]"
tenant_id = "[Tenant ID API Key]"
secret_key_name = "[Secret key Name]"
Secret_ID = "[Secret ID]"

authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id = client_id,
    client_credential = client_secret,
    authority = authority  
)

accounts = app.get_accounts()
if accounts:
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'])
else:
    result = None 

if not result:
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']) 

if 'access_token' in result:
    access_token = result['access_token']

    headers = {
        'Authorization' : f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
   
    api_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users'
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers = headers)   

    if response.status_code == 200:
        user_data = response.json()
        print(user_data)
    else:
        print(f"API Request Error: {response.status_code}-{response.content.decode('utf-8')}")       

else:
    print(f"Token Acquisition Error : {result.get('error')}-{result.get('error_description')}")
```

Answer (score 0):

> The error usually occurs if you missed adding required **API
> permissions** or granting **admin consent** to them. There is no need to add secret ID and secret name to generate token.

I registered one Azure AD application and added API permission without granting consent:

[image]

When I ran your code in my environment, I too got **same error** like below:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to grant **admin consent** to the added permission:

[image]

When I ran the same code again after granting admin consent, I got **response** successfully with user's data like below:

```py
import requests
import msal

client_id = "appId"
client_secret = "secret"
tenant_id = "tenantId"
#secret_key_name = "[Secret key Name]"
#Secret_ID = "[Secret ID]"

authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id = client_id,
    client_credential = client_secret,
    authority = authority  
)

accounts = app.get_accounts()
if accounts:
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'])
else:
    result = None 

if not result:
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']) 

if 'access_token' in result:
    access_token = result['access_token']

    headers = {
        'Authorization' : f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
   
    api_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users'
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers = headers)   

    if response.status_code == 200:
        user_data = response.json()
        print(user_data)
    else:
        print(f"API Request Error: {response.status_code}-{response.content.decode('utf-8')}")       

else:
    print(f"Token Acquisition Error : {result.get('error')}-{result.get('error_description')}")
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: thanks. Actually, I have been thinking about the same, but I am not able to the admin who gave the permissions. I will check it again.